# Xamarin.forms - How to detect enter press in entry inside a view model?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am developing an xamarin forms app based on mvvm pattern. I am looking for way to detect if user type Enter button. Event should call an command from viewModel class.

Could you guys share some tips? ;)

Answer (score 6):

Completed event is fired on press of enter key see [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.Entry.Completed/#Xamarin.Forms.Entry.Completed_Event).

You can attach your event handler on Completed event like this:

```
var testEntry = new Entry ();
```

`testEntry.Completed += (sender, e) => {`

```
//Called on enter key press
```

`};`

Comment: Yes. It was first what i found. I need to call command from viewModel class  `//Called on enter key press` in here. And its my problem ;/ I just noticed that title of my post is misleading..;/

Answer (score 3):

You could use an event to command behavior to bind the Completed event to a command on the view model.

[Details here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/turn-events-into-commands-behaviors/)

Answer (score 2):

If you have Entry defined in XAML page like:

```xml
<Entry x:Name="Entry" WidthRequest="400" Placeholder="Enter text" TextChanged="HandleTextChanged"/>
```

**In your C# code**

```cs
public void InitializeControls()
{
    Entry.Completed += (sender, e) => EntryCompleted(sender, e);
}

void EntryCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // what you want to do after press after Enter key press
}
```