# How to get event of Done button click of keyboard for Editor in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using an editor in my xamarin forms editor. I want that when user click on the Done button of the keyboard, the keyboard should hide and I can perform some action in it. But currently when I click on Done button it moves the cursor to the new line.

So how I can get the Done button click event for editor?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46292679/3244198) post.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can use `custom renderers` to achieve this.

For iOS:

```
 public class customEditorRender : EditorRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                // do whatever you want to the UITextView here!

                Control.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done;

                Control.ShouldChangeText = (text, range, replacementString) =>
                {
                    if (replacementString.Equals("\n"))
                    {
                        //hide keyboard here
                        Control.EndEditing(true);

                        //perform some action here


                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not good at Android but I think you can do the same action in Android.